# CAN protocol how to make use of candump utility

Tags: can, protocol, socket, tools

Can anyone help me out how to use -r parameter in the candump utility?

> -r (set socket receive buffer to size)

Wanted to verify: Configurable receive buffer feature.

I verified the above as follows:

In terminal 1: `cansend can0 001#001122334455`  -> sending 6 bytes of data

In terminal 2: `candump can0 -r 4`   -> but allocated the receiver buffer size as 4

Observed all the 6 bytes have been received: `can0 001 [6] 00 11 22 33 44 55`

Comment: The `-r` option uses `setsockopt()` to configure the receive buffer. 
The socket option `SO_RCVBUF` describes the minimum value as 256 (socket [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)).

Comment: hi @Velvet can you plz let me know how to make use of this parameter -r to verify Configurable receive buffer through an example

Comment: The `-r` option is used for the socket driver, not your application layer. If for instance the receive buffer of the socket is too small, you can increase it: `candump -r 8192 can0`